# collection_select using formtastic_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having two tables: `company` and `department`. In company table i have `"departmentname"` field for saving department name taken from department table. I am using `formtastic` form  for collection select in my view.

```
<%= set.input :departmentname ,:as => :select, :collection => Department.all) %>
```

i am getting department list, in my view. After saving `"departmentname"` field in Company Table is having department id and not name of the department.

How to save department name rather than id in my company table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is name of the field in `Department` table whose value will be in `departmentname` in `Company` table? I guess it is `name` and your `department` table structure is like:

```
id    name
1     department 1
2     department 2
```

Try it as below:

```
:collection => Hash[Department.all.map{|d| [d.name,d.name]}]
```

however, I guess the following will work too (not sure though)

```
:collection => Hash[Department.all.map{|d| [d.name]}]
```